# Align the entire table developed by tabularray to the left

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularray

I have a table developed by tabularray, but I could not find in the documentation how to align the entire table to the left to let the entire table being centered again.

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}


\begin{tblr}{
colspec={cccccccc},
rowspec={Q[gray!20]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]}, 
vline{2-8} = {0-1}{0.3pt,gray!50},
vline{2-8} = {2-7}{0.3pt,gray!30},
hline{1,2,8} = {0.1pt,azure5}}
Dataset  & \# clusters & \# Train neurons & \# Test neurons & \# Extra neurons & Architectures & Train loss & Test loss\\
1  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
2  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
3  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
4  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
5  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
6  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\

\end{tblr}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Insert `\noindent` immediately before `\begin{tblr}`.

Comment: I tried it now, it did not work.

Comment: Your table is far too wide to fit in the text block.

Comment: But there is still space on the left

Comment: The `\noindent` instruction suppresses the space that's otherwise inserted by a paragraph break. `\noindent`, by itself, will *not* let the table encroach into the left-hand margin.

Comment: Did you try the code on your machine?

Comment: I sure did. That's why I know that `\noindent` helps to align the left-hand edge of the table with the left-hand edge of the text block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is too large to be shown in the same line so I have two solutions for you :

1. Reduce the size of the table like this

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
> \usepackage{tabularray}
> \usepackage{graphicx}
> \begin{document}
> \scalebox{0.7}{
> \begin{tblr}{
> colspec={cccccccc},
> rowspec={Q[gray!20]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]}, 
> vline{2-8} = {0-1}{0.3pt,gray!50},
> vline{2-8} = {2-7}{0.3pt,gray!30},
> hline{1,2,8} = {0.1pt,azure5}}
> Dataset  & \# clusters & \# Train neurons & \# Test neurons & \# Extra neurons & Architectures & Train loss & Test loss\\
> 1  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
> 2  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
> 3  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
> 4  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
> 5  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
> 6  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
>
> \end{tblr}}
>
> \end{document}
> ```

2. Change the borders of the page :

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
> \usepackage{tabularray}
> \usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
> left=0.1in,right=0.5in,top=0.6in,bottom=0.5in,%
> footskip=.1in]{geometry}
> \begin{document}
> \begin{tblr}{
> colspec={cccccccc},
> rowspec={Q[gray!20]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]}, 
> vline{2-8} = {0-1}{0.3pt,gray!50},
> vline{2-8} = {2-7}{0.3pt,gray!30},
> hline{1,2,8} = {0.1pt,azure5}}
> Dataset  & \# clusters & \# Train neurons & \# Test neurons & \# Extra neurons & Architectures & Train loss & Test loss\\
> 1  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
> 2  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
> 3  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
> 4  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
> 5  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
> 6  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
>
> \end{tblr}
>
> \end{document}
> ```

Comment: Your first option works very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions:

1. Use:

   - `\centerline{...}` so that the table can overflow harmoniously on the two margins.
   - `font=\scriptsize` to reduce the size of the titles.
   - `colsep=1pt` to reduce spaces between columns.
2. Use:

   - `\rotatebox{angle}{text}` (from `graphicx`) to rotate the titles of the columns.

Note: with `tabularray`, `Z` denotes the last row of the table and `row{odd}` applies to odd rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\centerline{
  \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={cccccccc},
      colsep=1pt,
      % colors and lines for the table
      row{odd}={bg=gray!10},
      vline{2-8} = {0.3pt,gray!30},
      hline{1,2,Z} = {0.1pt,azure5},
      % colors and lines for the title row
      row{1}={font=\scriptsize,bg=gray!10},
      vline{2-8} = {0-1}{0.3pt,gray!50},
    }
    Dataset & \# clusters & \# Train neurons & \# Test neurons & \# Extra neurons & Architectures & Train loss & Test loss \\
    1       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
    2       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
    3       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
    4       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
    5       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
    6       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
  \end{tblr}
}

\lipsum[2]

\centerline{
  \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={cccccccc},
      % colors and lines for the table
      row{odd}={bg=gray!10},
      vline{2-8} = {0.3pt,gray!30},
      hline{1,2,Z} = {0.1pt,azure5},
      % colors and lines for the title row
      row{1}={cmd=\rotatebox{90},font=\footnotesize,bg=gray!10},
      vline{2-8} = {0-1}{0.3pt,gray!50},
    }
    Dataset & \# clusters & \# Train neurons & \# Test neurons & \# Extra neurons & Architectures & Train loss & Test loss \\
    1       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
    2       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
    3       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
    4       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
    5       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
    6       & Beta        & Gamma            & Alpha           & Beta             & Gamma         & Beta       & Gamma     \\
  \end{tblr}
}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that works smoothly.

Comment: Could you please help me out with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635061/add-caption-for-table-designed-by-tabularray?