# Add caption for table designed by tabularray

Tags: tables, captions, tabularray

I want to add the caption above the table. There is no information on the package documentation[here](https://ctan.mines-albi.fr/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf). The documentation only explains adding caption to long table which is not the case of mine.  Any help appreciated!

[image]

This is the code:

```
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\scalebox{0.8}{

\begin{tblr}[caption={"sdsdssdfsdfds"}]{
colspec={cccccccc},
rowspec={Q[gray!20]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]Q[gray!10]Q[]}, 
rowhead = 1,
vline{2-8} = {0-1}{0.3pt,gray!50},
vline{2-8} = {2-7}{0.3pt,gray!30},
hline{1,2,8} = {0.1pt,azure5}}
header  & header & header & header & header & header & header & header\\
1  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
2  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
3  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
4  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
5  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
6  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\

\end{tblr}

}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. How or where is `\scalebox` defined? Which document class do you employ?

Comment: I edited the code

Comment: For a caption you can put it in a `table` environment. Or use the `caption` or `capt-of` package that allows you to add captions with the `\captionof`command.

Comment: You can use the `longtblr` for this. I know that it is meant for use with long tables which extend over one page, but it will work in a case like this, where you have a short table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are confusing the `tblr` environment with the `table` environment. The former is for creating a tabular like structure, while the latter is the floating environment. The `caption` (and `label`) have to go in the floating environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Example caption}
    \label{tab:Example}
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={*{8}{c}},
            row{odd}={gray!10}, row{1}={gray!20},
            vline{2-Y} = {1}{0.3pt,gray!50},
            vline{2-Y} = {2-Z}{0.3pt,gray!30},
            hline{1,2,Z} = {0.1pt,azure5}
        }
        header  & header & header & header & header & header & header & header\\
        1  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
        2  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
        3  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
        4  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
        5  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
        6  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\   
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}     
            
\end{document}
```

[image: tblr output]

I also made some further improvements to your code

- `table` option for `xcolor` is not needed when using `tabularray`
- remove `rowhead` option, as it is only needed for `longtblr`
- avoid using `\scalebox` as it leads to inconsistent font sizes
- use `*{8}{c}` in `colspec` to repeat the `c` column `8` times
- replaced `rowspec` definition with `odd` option for row coloring. This is far more flexible, as it doesn't depend on the number of rows
- simplified `vline` and `hline` definition: you can use the letters `X`, `Y` and `Z` to refer to the last three `columns` (or `rows`)  respectively. This makes your code more readable and is also more flexible should you change the number of columns later

Comment: the doco for tabularray could be improved! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can replace `tblr` with `talltblr` to get the caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor} % tabularray doesn't need `table` option
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\scalebox{0.8}{
\begin{talltblr}[
  caption={"sdsdssdfsdfds"}
]{
  colspec={cccccccc},
  rowspec={Q[gray!20]QQ[gray!10]QQ[gray!10]QQ[gray!10]Q}, 
  %rowhead = 1, % only for long tables
  vline{2-8} = {0-1}{0.3pt,gray!50},
  vline{2-8} = {2-7}{0.3pt,gray!30},
  hline{1,2,8} = {0.1pt,azure5},
}
header  & header & header & header & header & header & header & header\\
1  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
2  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
3  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
4  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
5  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
6  & Beta & Gamma & Alpha & Beta & Gamma & Beta & Gamma\\
\end{talltblr}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, but it did not work.

Comment: @Phoenix if you are using overleaf, you need to download latest version and upload it to your project.

Comment: How can I do that please?

Comment: @Phoenix Download from here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.sty