# Creating advanced tables with tabularray

Tags: tables, tabularray

I've heard that instead of `tabular` `tabularray` should be used. And I think it's right because classic table is glitching out when combined with row colors. But I absolutely cannot figure out how to use `tabularray`.

In the code below I have provided main table created with `tabular`, and second table created with `tabularray`, which should be exact copy of the first one. Problem is that the secondary table doesn't look correctly, and doesn't even compile, because for reasons unknown `tabularray` does not support captions. At least not directly, I'm sure caption can be added, but this is also the thing that I can't do.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\definecolor{rowcol}{rgb}{0.7, 0.7, 0.7}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\title{TEST2}
\author{Anon}
\date{May 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

%main table
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\large
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}||c|c|c| } 
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Description} \\
\hhline{~---}
                  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\hline
\rowcolor{rowcol}
A & 11 & 11 & 11 \\
\hline
B & 12 & 11 & 12 \\
\hline
\rowcolor{rowcol}
C & 12 & 12 & 12 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Caption} \label{tablelabel}
\end{table}

%table above remake
\begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{
  hlines, vlines,
  colspec={X[l,m]|X[c,m] X[c,m] X[c,m]},
  column{1}={font=\bfseries},
  cell{1}{1,1} = {c=3}{c},
  row{2}={bg=rowcol},
  row{4}={bg=rowcol},
  row{6}={bg=rowcol}
}
  & Description \\
  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  A & 10 & 20 & 30 \\
  B & 15 & 25 & 35 \\
  C & 12 & 22 & 32 \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Table 2}
\label{tablelabel2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Basically same question as [Add caption for table designed by tabularray - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635061/add-caption-for-table-designed-by-tabularray) I think. Maybe try to fix your code according to that first

Comment: @user202729 if I would know how to fix my code I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: I think, you mean `tabular` instead of `table`, since the latter is the floating environment which can be used to position `tabular`s or `tblr`s or other table-like things on a page. Also, I would not say that one should use the `tabularray` package in general. It depends on your use case whether or not it is beneficial to use `tabularray´. Apart from all of that, the above code does not throw any erros for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem with the caption you have and actually it should not matter whether you place a `tabular` or a `tabularray` inside a `table` together with a `\caption`. Anyways, this should be a proper remake of the original table (but with nicer gaps where the doubled cell borders meet):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\definecolor{rowcol}{rgb}{0.7, 0.7, 0.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={ Q[c,m,wd=2cm] Q[c,m] Q[c,m] Q[c,m] },
  cells={font=\large},
  cell{1}{1}={r=2}{},
  cell{1}{2}={c=3}{},
  row{odd[3]}={bg=rowcol},
  hline{1-Z}={1}{-}{leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
  hline{3}={2}{-}{leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
  vlines,
  vline{2}={2}{-}{},
}
  & Description \\
  & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
  A & 10 & 20 & 30 \\
  B & 15 & 25 & 35 \\
  C & 12 & 22 & 32 \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Caption} \label{tablelabel2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I replaced `hlines` by `hline{1-Z}={1}{-}{leftpos=0, rightpos=0}` to achieve the nicer gaps. Also, using `row{odd[3]}={bg=rowcol}`, you can set the background for all odd rows starting from row 3 in one go. And as suggested by Zarko, it is probably better to use `\centering` instead of a nested `center` environment.

Comment: +1 for lines, but I would remove ˙center˙ environment and replace it by `\cantering` command.